# Media queries & Angular Material

Tags: angular, media-queries

Can someone hep me  understand the importance of media queries even when we use angular material to develop a responsive application.
Do we still have to worry about it ? is material not taking care of it for us ?

Comment: This question is too broad and subjective.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes and no.

There is no need to create your own media queries.

To have a responsive app means, that the main layout will take care of the window sizes. Main layout means that you think in columns and rows.

To controll this responsive behaviour, you can use angular/flex.

First: you have to install this by

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout -s
```

You will find a documentation and a lot of demos here: [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) and here: [Demos](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Live-Demos)

You can try out this: [angular-project-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-project-generator). The generated project seed uses angular/flex and the angular mat-sidenav.

If you want to write your own media queries, don't use 200px, 300px or 500px. Try to use same values used here: [Responsive API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API)

```
default angular breakpoints:
  xs: begin: 0, end: 599.9px
  sm: begin: 600px, end: 959.9px
  md: begin: 960px, end: 1279.9px
  lg: begin: 1280px, end: 1919.9px
  xl: begin: 1920px, end: 4999.99px
```

In some of my angular project, I used this scss, which generates some responsive helper classes:

```
    @charset "UTF-8";

// see node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/_mq.scss

// Non-overlapping Material Design breakpoints
// @type map
$breakpoints: (
  xs: (
    begin: 0,
    end: 599.9px,
  ),
  sm: (
    begin: 600px,
    end: 959.9px,
  ),
  md: (
    begin: 960px,
    end: 1279.9px,
  ),
  lg: (
    begin: 1280px,
    end: 1919.9px,
  ),
  xl: (
    begin: 1920px,
    end: 4999.99px,
  ),
) !default;

// Overlapping breakpoints that are greater than defined
// Material Design breakpoints
// @type map
$overlapping-gt: (
  gt-xs: 600px,
  gt-sm: 960px,
  gt-md: 1280px,
  gt-lg: 1920px,
) !default;

// Overlapping breakpoints that are less than defined
// Material Design breakpoints
// @type map
$overlapping-lt: (
  lt-sm: 599.9px,
  lt-md: 959.9px,
  lt-lg: 1279.9px,
  lt-xl: 1919.9px,
) !default;

@mixin layout-bp($bp) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $bp) {
    $min: map-get(map-get($breakpoints, $bp), begin);
    $max: map-get(map-get($breakpoints, $bp), end);
    @media (min-width: $min) and (max-width: $max) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else if map-has-key($overlapping-gt, $bp) {
    $min: map-get($overlapping-gt, $bp);
    @media (min-width: $min) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else if map-has-key($overlapping-lt, $bp) {
    $max: map-get($overlapping-lt, $bp);
    @media (max-width: $max) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

$allkeys: map_keys(
  map_merge($breakpoints, map_merge($overlapping-gt, $overlapping-lt))
);

@each $key in $allkeys {
  @include layout-bp($key) {
    .ge-display-none-#{$key} {
      display: none !important;
    }
    .ge-display-block-#{$key} {
      display: block !important;
    }
    .ge-display-inline-#{$key} {
      display: inline !important;
    }
    .ge-padding-0-#{$key} {
      padding: 16px !important;
    }
    .ge-padding-16px-#{$key} {
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
    .ge-margin-0-#{$key} {
      margin: 16px !important;
    }
    .ge-margin-16px-#{$key} {
      margin: 0 !important;
    }
  }
}
```

You can put the scss code in here to see the generatet media queries: [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Answer (score 1):

+Adding to the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61940309/5043867) answer

Yes off course Angular material will take care of it but to the scope of its component only not to the component you created say might be button/Sliders or it could be anything.

Media queries basically let you to Adjust and customize your layout template as per your choice on different screen resolution. 
For example, you want on mobile Material button width should be `200px`, on a tablet it should be `300px` and on desktop `500px` and so on, this could be achieved using Media Queries.

I hope this clears many of your questions.